# Can we use KKT condition to derive the dual of an optimization function given that Slater's condition holds?

Tags: real-analysis, optimization, convex-analysis, convex-optimization

For example, in the derivation of SVM's dual, can we say that the optimization meets the Slater's condition by checking its convexity and feasibility, then use K.K.T condition to get the partial derivative of the primal variables and let them be zero. Finally, we eliminate the primal variables by plugging in the result from the K.K.T condition into the primal problem, and transform it into the dual problem.

Comment: Slat'ers condition does not require a problem to be convex. Slater's condition together with convexity are used to conclude that the duality gap is zero. The dual can be derived independent from Slater's condition.

Comment: @LinAlg Yes, what I mean here is can we directly use derivatives of the primal variables without mentioning the KKT conditions or we are allowed to use KKT condition to derive its dual given that duality gap is zero?

Comment: Neither. You derive the dual by optimizing the Lagrangian over the primal variables. Slater's condition or convexity do not come into play.

Comment: @LinAlg Isn't acquiring the partial derivative ant let it be zero corresponding to optimizing the Lagrangian over the primal variables?

Comment: No, because you would miss bound constraints on the primary variables. For nonconvex problems the optimum is not necessarily where the derivative is 0. Moreover, the KKT conditions entail dual feasibility and complementary slackness, which you don't need.